# jQuery AJAX / Posting data with symbols

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am sending quite a few values with my AJAX call, like this:

```
var postData = "aid="+aid+"&lid="+lid+"&token="+token+"&count="+count+"&license="+license;
postData = postData + "&category="+category+"&event_name="+event_name+"&set_menu="+set_menu;
postData = postData + "&set_id="+set_id+"&location="+location+"&delay="+delay;
```

and then sending the call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'ajax/createFolderID.asp',
    dataType : 'html',
    data : postData,
    success : function() { do something },
    complete : function() { do something },
    error : function() { do something }
});
```

The problem is, one of the querystring values, "event_name", comes from user input. If the user enters an ampersand (&) symbol, the postData string breaks and won't send anything after that symbol.

> Example case: &event_name=D&G Clothing Launch
>   Party&set_menu=existing...

I understand what is going wrong, but not so sure what the best fix would be. Do I convert those characters to something else, or is there a way of escaping them? Also, are there any other characters that will cause harm to the script, like plus (+) or minus (-) signs, or apostrophes (')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the postData to jQuery as a map, it will encode the components for you:

```
var postData = { aid: aid,
                 lid: lid,
                 ...
```

If you really need to pass a string, you should use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode the user data.

The W3C has [some more information on form encoding](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1).

Comment: Thanks, I will read this. The string in question is only a short one, an event name, and comes from my office staff, not general public. I used escape(variable) as @Oybek suggested.

Comment: The `escape` function is deprecated.  It is better to use the more specific `encodeURIComponent` function.  (Although escape will probably work). see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: Nearly two years on I find my question (this question) on Google. After a bit more experience gained, I now think this is the better answer, so I have swapped the previously accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 6):

Escape each of your values.

```
var postData = "aid="+escape(aid)+"&lid="+escape(lid) ... ;
```

Comment: This worked great thanks. It was just the event_name variable that could possibly contain bad characters, so I escaped just that one.

Answer (score 1):

First use a Map.

```
post = {
    "aid":aid,
    "lid":lid,
    "token":token
    ...
}
```

Then generate url-encoded string.

```
a=[];
for(var x in post){
    a.push(encodeURIComponent(x)+"="+encodeURIComponent(post[x]));
}
var postData = a.join("&");
```

**Update 1:**
If you are using jQuery no need to generate url-encoded string. Just pass the map.

**Update 2:**
`escape` is not good as it only handles with *ASCII*. So using `encodeURIComponent`. <sup>[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)</sup> Thanks @SamuelEdwinWard

Comment: Better to use `encodeURIComponent` rather than `escape` (as jQuery does).

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
 postData = encodeURIComponent (postData);
```

before lauching it.

escape, unescape, encodeURI, encodeURIComponent are various methods you may need using Ajax.
However, if you use escape (http://www.google.com), you will also escape **://**, destroying your URI.
That's why you should use encodeURI, or encodeURIComponent.
See also [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: Escaping this way will collapse the whole your query string. The result will be the same as posting like this `http://example.com/path/?somegarbage`